# How create UIImage from bytes?

Tags: iphone, image, uiimage, nsdata, cgimage

I need in UIImage created from my colors (for example, i need in image 1x1 pixel with black color).

I've got array:

```
unsigned char *color[] = {0, 0, 0, 1};
```

How can i create UIImage from this array ?

I've try

```
 unsigned char *bytes[4] = {0,0,0,1};
 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:4];
 UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

but this method has no result...

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to create a bitmap context (using CGBitmapContextCreate()), and draw into that. This requires using [CoreGraphics](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreGraphics/Reference/CoreGraphics_Framework/). Then take your context and use CGBitmapContextCreateImage() to create an CGImageRef out of it. Finally, use +[UIImage imageWithCGImage:] to convert that CGImageRef to a UIImage.

Comment: Thanks, i'm trying this, but i have problem with alpha channel.

I've got picture with ALPHA channel, and i try change color (for example: from yellow to green) and i think alpha must keep...

I've try this: http://milytia.org/paste/117 when brush is RGBA bytes array.

When i run it i have artefacts on my generated image (on ALPHA place)...

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, all!

This is solved my problem.

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/23525-cgimagecreate-alpha.html