# How to convert (OS_dispatch_data *) 5018112 bytes into NSData to put into UIImage

Tags: objective-c, opencv, uiimage, dispatch-async

I've been looking for an answer to this and some seem like they might be what I need but I'm not sure.  I found this [Question #9152851](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152851/how-to-convert-dispatch-data-t-to-nsdata) and this [Question #2617625](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617625/how-create-uiimage-from-bytes) and poked around on a bunch of links but I need some direction here.

Essentially, I'm dispatching an async call to process an image using OpenCV.  You can see by the code here that I'm turning it into NSData * before sending it back to my delegate.

```
NSData *proccessedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:processedImage.data length:(processedImage.rows * processedImage.cols)];        
[self.delegate onProcessedBitmapReady:proccessedData withFocusQuality:focusQuality];
```

But when I get back to my delegate, my processedBitmap is of type (OS_dispatch_data *) and contains a value of bytes.  So, when I try to set the UIImage, it gets set to null.

```
- (void)onProcessedBitmapReady:(NSData *)processedBitmap withFocusQuality:(double)focusQuality
{
    //Use comverted image from self.captureCommand onComplete
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:processedBitmap];
    [self saveImage:image];
}
```

Here is a screen capture of the values:

[image: Imgur]

So, how do I convert those bytes (or whatever they are) into something that I can stuff into a UIImage?

Thank you in advance for your help.

------------------------------------------------------- **Adding a new image** -----------------------------------------

[image: My Bytes]

Does this new image help?

Thank you.

Comment: Does onProcessedBitmapReady retain the NSData object? Is the NSData object retained elsewhere? Are you using ARC?

Comment: Looks like reclaimed memory to me, your NSData was not retained properly.

Comment: My processedBitmap is my NSData.  I see 5018112 bytes in it.  The only thing weird is that it is of type OS_dispatch_data *.  Does that mean that the memory has been reclaimed?

Comment: OK.  I created a property with (nonatomic, strong) and now I retrieve that value from my object and it still says that it is of type OS_dispatch_data *.  Could that just be because I am calling it in an asynch call using GCD?

Comment: `NSData`, like many other Foundation classes, is actually a class cluster, meaning that `NSData` is just providing the interface. `OS_dispatch_data` sounds like a specialized subclass that is used internally by Apple to transfer `NSData` stuff around blocks, but I might be wrong though. If it behaves like an `NSData` instance, it probably is, and the image is just in a format that isn't recognized by `UIImage`

Comment: @JustSid - You are correct!  I had to create a CGContextRef using CGBitmapContextCreate and then create a CGImageRef using the CGBitmapContextCreateImage and then create a UIImage using imageWithCGImage.  Answer the question and I'll give you the points.

Comment: @Lucy: Could have made a post with your own answer ? about how did you got around the issue ?

Comment: @Shailesh - I used the CVImageConverter code by Artem Myagkov posted here:  https://code.google.com/p/opencv-on-ios/source/browse/trunk/utilities/CVImageConverter.mm?r=11

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`NSData` is actually a class cluster which just provides the interface, and there are multiple special implementations for it around. It appears that `OS_dispatch_data` is such a special implementations made to pass data objects around blocks, especially since your `UIImage` creation doesn't crash (as it would if you would pass it a non `NSData` object, or just garbage memory). Instead, it looks like `UIImage` simply doesn't recognize the format the image is in!

By the way, Apple has a great guide about the concept of class clusters, which can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html).

Comment: Specifically, OS_dispatch_data is a dispatch_data_t, from libdispatch. In iOS 7 and Mavericks, dispatch datas can be freely cast to NSData and are in fact NSData subclasses (if and only if Foundation is linked in the process of course).