# create image from rgb data in swift

Tags: swift, bitmap, core-graphics

Say I would like to have a 10x10 image filled with different RGB colours

How do I create the Core Graphics bitmap context, and draw each pixel in?

I have searched but cannot find any resources on writing to a Core Graphics bitmap context.

[How create UIImage from bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617625/how-create-uiimage-from-bytes) says what I need to do but does not say how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to draw to a bitmap context

```
let width = 10
let height = 10
```

- A variable of type `[UInt8]` to store RGB data (call it `data` for example), where data[0] to data[2] is the first pixels red green blue values between 0-255, data[3] to data[5] is the second pixels red green blue values between 0-255. data.count must equals `height * width`
- make a cfdata object from that variable
- pass that cfdata to cfdataprovider initiliaser
- pass that cfdataprovider to cgimage initialiser

congratulations you now how a cgimage object with pixel values taken from `data`